# Flutter active internet connection

Tags: flutter, dart, connectivity

Is there any way I can check whether internet connection on user mobile is active, rather than whether it's Wi-Fi or mobile data is turned on.

I tried using the package [Connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus)

It's giving me whether Wi-Fi or mobile data is turned on. It doesn't really check it's active internet connection. Could you please help me to sort out.

Below is my code

```
class ConnectivityProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  late bool _isOnline = false;
  bool get isOnline => _isOnline;

  ConnectivityProvider() {
    Connectivity _connectivity = Connectivity();

    _connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen((result) async {
      if (result == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        _isOnline = false;
        notifyListeners();
      } else {
        _isOnline = true;
        notifyListeners();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this package : internet_connection_checker

https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker

"The reason this package exists is that connectivity_plus package cannot reliably determine if a data connection is actually available."